# Which one is correct 会社名前 or 会社の名前?

Tags: word-choice, usage, set-phrases, phrases

I'm a beginner in Japanese language. In English, "Company Name" and "Name of Company" are basically the same. In Japanese, are those two the same or different? Which one should I use?

- 会社名前
- 会社の名前

Comment: You should use the 2nd not the 1st: The equivalents of "the company name" and "the company's name" are explained below.

Comment: (We also have 社名... sorry if I'm only confusing you)

Answer (score 7):

会社の名前{なまえ} consists of two nouns, one describing the other. The one with の is in genitive case which is used to indicate possession in this case. It's roughly equivalent to *'s* or *of* in English: *company's name* or *the name of the company* (both are translated to 会社の名前). Note that 名前 is a native Japanese word and it uses kun-yomi reading of the kanji in this case.

As it happens often in Japanese, there's also a Sino-Japanese word with the same meaning which uses on-yomi readings only. For company name it is 会社名{かいしゃめい} or 社名{しゃめい} (not 会社名前). As a rough rule, those kind of words are usually more formal then equivalent native Japanese words.

Please also note that Japanese and English grammar don't work in the same way and order of words in both language is often different and has a different significance. You cannot really directly translate word by word.

Answer (score 4):

会社{かいしゃ}の名前{なまえ} is grammatically fine, and while compound nouns are sometimes formed by simply eliminating the の particle (e.g.,本{ほん}の棚{たな} -> 本棚{ほんだな} or 勉強{べんきょう}の不足{ふそく} -> 勉強不足{べんきょうぶそく}), in this case the word you are looking for is: 会社名{かいしゃめい} (the *on-yomi* of 名 is generally used in compound nouns and has the same meaning as 名前{なまえ} as a whole: *name*).

Answer (score 3):

One of the uses of the の particle (that you will learn early on in Japanese) is to show possession. "Company Name" is the same as "Company's Name". Company's Name = 会社の名前